# Blackberry ObjectChoiceField Not Showing drop down list

Tags: blackberry

ObjectChoiceField not working because the below code:

```java
protected boolean navigationUnclick(int status, int time) {
    return true;
}
```

I have added this code to remove the menus on touchevent. Means I have made a custom bottom tab and adding and deleting verticalfields on screen. When i touch any HorizontalField it shows menu that's why i added the above code.

This is my code contains `ObjectChoiceField` added in horizontalfield:

```java
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

import com.ec.pleasewaitpopup.PleaseWaitPopupScreen;
import com.np.naijapings.ApplicationFont;
import com.np.naijapings.Constant;
import com.np.naijapings.TabControlScreen;
import com.np.naijapings.intermediateclasses.GetUserListIntermediator;
import com.tv.servercommunication.WebServiceDetails;

public class FindUsersScreen extends VerticalFieldManager implements FieldChangeListener{

    private VerticalFieldManager _mainVfm;
    private VerticalFieldManager _contentVfm;

    private BitmapField _headerBmp;
    private EncodedImage _bitmap;

    private LabelField _gender;
    private LabelField _age;
    private LabelField _religion;

    private ObjectChoiceField _genderChoiceField;
    private ObjectChoiceField _ageChoiceField;
    private ObjectChoiceField _religionChoiceField;

    private ButtonField _findUser;

    private static String[] _genderChoices={"Both gender","Male","Female"};
    private static String[] _ageChoices={"Any age","18-25","26-30","31-35","36-45","46-50"};
    private String[] _religionChoices={"Any religion","Hindu","Muslim"};

    public FindUsersScreen(){
        //HEADER IMG
        _bitmap = EncodedImage.
        getEncodedImageResource("find-user_header.png");
        _headerBmp = new BitmapField(Constant.sizePic(_bitmap, _bitmap.getHeight(), _bitmap.getWidth()));

        //MAIN VFM
        _mainVfm=new VerticalFieldManager();

        //CONTENT VFM
        final Bitmap tabBackGroundImage = Bitmap
        .getBitmapResource("finduserscr_bg.png");
        _contentVfm=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                int y = FindUsersScreen.this.getManager().getVerticalScroll();
                graphics.drawBitmap( 0, y, tabBackGroundImage.getWidth(), tabBackGroundImage.getHeight(), tabBackGroundImage, 0, 0 );
                super.paint( graphics );
                }
        };

        //CREATE WIDGETS
        _gender=new LabelField("Gender");
        _genderChoiceField=new ObjectChoiceField("Gender", _genderChoices,0){
            protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {

                return super.touchEvent(message);
            }
        };
        _age=new LabelField("Age");
        _ageChoiceField=new ObjectChoiceField("Age", _ageChoices,0);
        _religion=new LabelField("Religion");
        _religionChoiceField=new ObjectChoiceField("Religion", _religionChoices,0);
        _findUser=new ButtonField("    Find Users    ",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);


        _findUser.setChangeListener(this);

        //SET FONT TYPE
        /*_gender.setFont(ApplicationFont.labelFont_16);
        _genderChoiceField.setFont(ApplicationFont.labelFont_16);
        _ageChoiceField.setFont(ApplicationFont.labelFont_16);
        _age.setFont(ApplicationFont.labelFont_20);
        _religionChoiceField.setFont(ApplicationFont.labelFont_20);
        _religion.setFont(ApplicationFont.labelFont_20);
*/
        //SET MARGIN
        /*_gender.setMargin(5,20,5,20);
        _age.setMargin(5,20,5,20);
        _religion.setMargin(5,20,5,20);
    */
        _contentVfm.setMargin(15,30,15,0);
        _genderChoiceField.setMargin(10,5,5,5);
        _religionChoiceField.setMargin(10,5,5,5);
        _ageChoiceField.setMargin(10,5,5,5);
        _findUser.setMargin(10,80,20,80);
        _contentVfm.setMargin(30,10,30,10);

        //ADD FIELDS TO CONTENT VFM
        //_contentVfm.add(_gender);
        _contentVfm.add(_genderChoiceField);
        //_contentVfm.add(_age);
        _contentVfm.add(_ageChoiceField);
        //_contentVfm.add(_religion);
        _contentVfm.add(_religionChoiceField);
        _contentVfm.add(_findUser);
        _mainVfm.add(_headerBmp);
        _mainVfm.add(_contentVfm);
        add(_mainVfm);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if(field==_findUser){
            Object obAgeRange = _ageChoiceField.getChoice(_ageChoiceField.getSelectedIndex());
            String ageRange = obAgeRange.toString();

            Object obgender = _genderChoiceField.getChoice(_genderChoiceField.getSelectedIndex());
            String gender = obgender.toString();

            Object obReligion = _religionChoiceField.getChoice(_religionChoiceField.getSelectedIndex());
            String religion = obReligion.toString();

            GetUserListIntermediator getUserListIntermediator=new GetUserListIntermediator(ageRange,gender,religion);
            PleaseWaitPopupScreen.showScreenAndWait(getUserListIntermediator, Constant.PLEASE_WAIT_TEXT);
        }
    }

}
```

could anyone answer me how to solve this problem.

Comment: why did you link touch events with navigation click events?

Answer (score 2):

You don't get drop-down list because the field code does not process `unclick` event. You have intercepted and consumed this event (via `return true;`) before your field can process it.

Try this code for your event handler.

```
protected boolean navigationUnclick(int status, int time) {
        super.navigationUnclick(status, time);
        return true;
}
```